# Cannot find linux commands in docker container (Windows docker desktop)

Tags: docker, tomcat, dockerfile, command

I am new to docker, and now trying to create a tomcat container (on windows 10 docker desktop).
In the log looks like the tomcat is running, but no command can be found in the terminal.

[image: terminal]

and I cannot access localhost:8080 either.

I am not sure what need to be added. This is the DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM redhat/ubi8:8.4

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /usr

RUN tar zxvf jdk-8u261-linux-x64.tar.gz

RUN tar zxvf apache-tomcat-8.5.40.tar.gz

ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/jdk1.8.0_261"

ENV CLASSPATH="$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar"

ENV CATALINA_HOME="/usr/apache-tomcat-8.5.40"

ENV PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/lib:$CATALINA_HOME/bin"

CMD ["/usr/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Appriciate your help!

I tried to edit ENV PATH, but not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for asking questions about coding/programming. Your question probably belongs to another Stack Exchange site, such as superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't know how you run your container, you probably forgot to provide the `-p` flag during your `docker run` command to tell docker to publish the port. According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port.

So now, you can publish the container port to your host port like this:

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 ....
```